# Is there any way to run "adb devices" from HTML page?

Tags: javascript, android, html, adb

I want to create simple webpage(HTML or etc.) and provide one button, up on clicking the button, it triggers "adb devices" through command prompt and get the answer and print it on the webpage.

Is it possible? I have look around and found that people are using JavaScript within HTML to call cmd.exe and executes some command but only in Internet explorer.

Appreciate if somebody guide me through simple example which can be run on Chrome/Firefox browser.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Do you know what a HUGE security hole that would be?  It would basically mean any website would have total control over your computer.

Comment: thanks, i thought so.. but then found "new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell"); " and its usage for IE. Let me know if you can think of anyway where I can post "adb devices" output on webpage through clickable button.

Comment: @KSoni ActiveX hasn't been supported in a decade, and is considered one of the biggest security holes ever written.   No browser other than IE ever supported it.  There is no way to do what you want, what you're requesting is to give shell access to a browser.  That basically gives a random webpage the ability to do anything it wants to the computer.  Nobody supports that.

Comment: @KSoni, you can try https://openstf.io/, it provides a way to run adb command from browser.

Comment: It doesn't run it on the local machine. It runs it on a remote device in their cloud. Totally different. But if you want that Amazon has a serVice as well